# How to build Docker container from existing image

Tags: asp.net, docker

How to edit docker compose, such that it uses existing images to build containers and not build images on the spot?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `docker-compose up` does the trick. Previously was using `docker compose up --build` which build the images even when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In docker-compose file mention your existing image from the image registry. `docker-compose up` will build the existing image. This is basic functionality.